# How to change the ROS_DISTRO variable?

Tags: ros, bashrc, ros-hydro, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had hydro installed on my raspberry pi earlier, then i removed it to install kinetic, everything seemed to be fine except the ROS_DISTRO variable. I tried the .bashrc rile there was no mention of hydro so i tried logging in and out but still no luck i also tried the export ROS_DISTRO command that didnt work either. sorry if this is a easy answer im new to ros. any help you could give would be awesome!

Thanks for you reply, I looked through the .bashrc and the only thing there is `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` line.

```
`# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
#[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \\\$\[\033[00m\] '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\\\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
#alias ll='ls -l'
#alias la='ls -A'
#alias l='ls -CF'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273691/how-to-change-the-ros_distro-variable?/) by [pacifickid9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32335/pacifickid9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-21**:
Did you copy-paste your `.bashrc` twice?

**Comment by [pacifickid9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32335/pacifickid9/) on 2017-10-21**:
yes i think i did. just fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's essentially just an environment variable, so an `export ROS_DISTRO=...` should work.

**But**: you shouldn't (need to) change it, as it's automatically set by the `setup.bash` scripts that are in the root of the ROS install directory.

It would be best if you can try to find out *why* that variable is being set (ie: by which file).

Looking through your `.bashrc` is indeed a good idea. Check for lines starting with `source /opt/...` or `source /some/path/in/hour/home_dir`. It could also be that you have a line already that sets the variable. Look for `export ROS_DISTRO=...`.

Whatever you do, it's infinitely better to figure out where that variable is getting set than to try and change its value manually.

---

> I had `hydro` installed on my raspberry pi earlier, then i removed it to install `kinetic`, everything seemed to be fine except the `ROS_DISTRO` variable.

Just to make sure:

- what OS is this (Debian?)
- you "had hydro" before, now Kinetic: Hydro and Kinetic do not have overlapping install targets: did you upgrade your OS for that?
- how did you install ROS? Seeing as you have a RPi: from sources? Or `.deb`s?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pacifickid9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32335/pacifickid9/) on 2017-10-21**:
`cat /etc/os-release` gave me `VERSION="8 (jessie)"` and `ID_LIKE=debian` so im not sure which im running. maybe that is my problem. and i followed the process in this tutorial to install kinetic: http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

**Comment by [pacifickid9](https://answers.ros.org/users/32335/pacifickid9/) on 2017-10-21**:
and i used this tutorial to install hydro http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Setting%20up%20Hydro%20on%20RaspberryPi does this help at all? i dont believe that i upgraded any OS

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-21**:
So you build from sources both times? Did you reuse the same `catkin_ws` for that? And did you build everything in a 'clean' terminal (ie: your Hydro workspace was not `source`d)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-21**:
Can you tell us what the value is of `ROS_DISTRO` in `/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/catkin/profile.d/10.ros.sh`?

It's set near the top of the file.